# Настройка webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Уже несколько дней как начал осваивать webpack. Пытался настроить webpack-dev-server столкнулся с проблемой, что при запуске он ищет файл index.html, но дело в том, что формирование html странички у меня происходит на стороне сервера... Как-то можно его подружить с моим сервером, чтобы он запросом стучался и доставал уже html оттуда? Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста! Любые замечания по настройке тоже приветствуются. Спасибо заранее.

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const argv = require('yargs').argv;

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');

const isDevelopment = argv.mode === 'development';

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  entry: {
    main: [
      '../src/js/common.js',
      '../src/js/main.js',
    ],
    map: '../src/js/map.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: isDevelopment ? 'js/[name].js' : 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: isDevelopment ? 'js/[name].js' : 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: './'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'styles': '../css/style.css',
      'bootstrapCss': 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
      'bootstrapJs': 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
      'datetimepickerCss': 'jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css',
      'datetimepickerJs': 'jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        //exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        loader: 'handlebars-loader',
        options: {
            knownHelpersOnly: false,
            partialDirs: [path.resolve(__dirname, './views/partials')]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          !isDevelopment ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              convertToAbsoluteUrls: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: [
                !isDevelopment ? require('postcss-import') : () => {},
                !isDevelopment ? require('cssnano') : () => {},
                
                require('autoprefixer')({
                  browsers: ['last 2 versions']
                }),

                require('postcss-preset-env')({
                  stage: 3,
                  browsers: ['last 5 versions', '> 5%'],
                  features: {
                    'custom-media-queries': true
                  }
                })
                
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              publicPath: '../img',
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'img/'
            }
          },
          "img-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            publicPath: './fonts',
            name: isDevelopment ? '[name].[ext]' : '[name][hash].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'css/fonts/'
          }
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  performance: { hints: false },
  devServer: {
    watchContentBase: true,
    contentBase: [path.join(__dirname, 'views'), path.join(__dirname, 'routes'), path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
    port: 3030,
    overlay: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    proxy: {
      '/': "http://localhost:3010",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  },
  devtool: isDevelopment ? 'eval-sourcemap' : false,
  plugins: [

    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({   
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'/*,
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      "Bootstrap": "bootstrap.js"*/
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: isDevelopment ? 'css/[name].css' : 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: '../src/img',
      to: 'img'
    }]),
    new ManifestPlugin(),
    !isDevelopment ? new ImageminPlugin({
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i
    }) : () => {},],
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
          sourceMap: true,
          uglifyOptions: {
            output: {comments: false},
            compress: {
              inline: false,
              drop_console: true
            },
          },
        }),
      ],
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
      }
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

scripts из package.json:

```js
"scripts": {
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "server": "nodemon --watch routes --watch server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
 }
```